# Where are the installed R packages?

Tags: r

Where are the installed R packages?

For example, after installing packages with 'install.packages("mlbench")' and so on, only "The downloaded binary packages are in C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2XB0sh\downloaded_packages" is a piece of related info from the console messages.

However, I fail to find them at all after scouring my computer according to package names (not just listing them with 'installed.packages()'). This question seems very difficult for me, but strangely I found almost no answer online. Where are the installed packages on the local computer?

Comment: Have a look at `?install.packages` (`lib` parameter) and `?.libPaths`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can view the location by running the  following:

```
.libPaths()
#[1] "C:/Users/ujjwal/Documents/R/win-library/3.1" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library"
```

R packages are installed into libraries, which are directories in the file system containing a subdirectory for each package installed there.

R comes with a single library, `R_HOME/library` which is the value of the R object `.Library` containing the standard and recommended packages. At the lowest level `.libPaths()` can be used to add paths to the collection of libraries or to report the current collection.

R will automatically make use of a site-specific library `R_HOME/site-library` if this exists. This location can be overridden by setting `.Library.site` in `R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site`. For more details see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#DOCF14).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found that there are two R folders installed (one R and one  RRO) in my computer, and I just searched the R folder previously.